# "Reaction does not exist" when I want to delete a reaction

Tags: getstream-io

When writing my tests in Laravel with the Get Stream Laravel wrapper, I want to test to deleting a reaction.

I basically do this:

```
    $client = FeedManager::getClient();
    $reactions = $client->reactions()->filter('user_id' , $this->user->id);
    $client->reactions()->delete($reactions['results'][0]['id']);
```

The result is this:

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `DELETE https://api.stream-io-api.com/api/v1.0/reaction/e9a919f2-2e28-4c5d-889e-c5f60b5880e9/` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{"detail":"Reaction does not exist","status_code":404,"code":16,"exception":"DoesNotExistException","duration":"1.69ms"}
```

I can confirm $reactions is not empty and give me a valid response.
In my base application it works as expected, but my test is failing for some reason. 
What could be wrong?

Comment: It seems there was a small wrong patch at the time you were testing. It's fixed and should be working. Let me know if you still see the issue.